# Using Artifactory instead of ECR

Tags: docker, artifactory, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

We've just brought Artifactory into our organization.  We have a lot of Fargate stacks that are pulling the Docker images from ECR.  We now want to pivot and store our Docker images in Artifactory and tell Fargate to pull the images from Artifactory.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An Artifactory repository for Docker images is a Docker registry in every way, and one that you can access transparently with the Docker client ([see documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Docker+Registry#DockerRegistry-RegistriesandRepositories))

In Artifactory, start by [creating a local Docker repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Docker+Registry#DockerRegistry-LocalDockerRepositories), then follow the "[Set Me Up](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Docker+Registry#DockerRegistry-SetMeUp)" instructions for that repository to upload/deploy your docker images to it.

The "Set Me Up" dialog for the Docker repository also provides the steps to have your docker clients consume/download the images from your Docker repository/registry. You would just have to replace the references of ECR with the one for your Artifactory docker repository/registry in your docker client commands.

This [documentation page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Getting+Started+with+Artifactory+as+a+Docker+Registry) provides step-by-step information on how to use Artifactory as a Docker registry.

Artifactory also provides the capabilities of [Remote Docker repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Docker+Registry#DockerRegistry-RemoteDockerRepositories), which provides proxying/caching of external registries, and [Virtual Docker repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Docker+Registry#DockerRegistry-VirtualDockerRepositories) for the aggregation of both local and remote repositories into one single entry point.

Comment: I already have the local docker repo set up and I'm pushing to it.  So the artifacts are there.  Now, it's about telling ECS to go get the artifact.  I am following this guide here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-private-registry-authentication-support-for-aws-fargate/

Comment: It looks like there are only two things that I need to tell ECS....the path to the objects and the user/password injection via a Secrets Manager ARN (I already have the IAM stuff set up).

Comment: So, here is the Artifactory endpoint to the artifacts: docker-dev-local/grafana/8.3.3-8b54c0c8c4bf0975f59afb1a6198c5a15472c0db/ based on the doc above it looks like the first part of the endpoint spec above is the user name, which in this case would be "docker-dev-local".  UNLESS then they want me to pre-pend a user name as follows: myusername/docker-dev-local/grafana/8.3.3-8b54c0c8c4bf0975f59afb1a6198c5a15472c0db/

Comment: The user name would be my user name and the password would be the token that I generated from the Artifactory dashboard.  Those two values would be stored in Secrets Manager.